# Problem knitting Rmd with vitae package, multiple-bibliographies.lua error

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

When attempting to knit my vitae from Rmd using the vitae package I am seeing the following error:

```
    Error running filter /tmp/RtmpLl0xn9/multiple-bibliographies.lua:
    /tmp/RtmpLl0xn9/multiple-bibliographies.lua:34: attempt to compare string with table
    stack traceback:
         /tmp/RtmpLl0xn9/multiple-bibliographies.lua:34: in function </tmp/RtmpLl0xn9/multiple-bibliographies.lua:32>
         /tmp/RtmpLl0xn9/multiple-bibliographies.lua:32: in main chunk
    Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
```

I see the same error when using the default Curie template content for any of the supplied templates. I've tried a variety of Rmd files, have updated all my r packages, and am at a bit of a loss for where to go next.

#### Reproduction

1. In rstudio, select File -> New File -> R Markdown
2. Select From Template
3. Select "Curriculum Vitae (Awesome-CV format)"
4. When the Rmd file loads click "knit"
5. See the below error

#### System

I am using:

- R version 4.0.3
- Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.1)
- Rstudio 1.2.5001
- vitae 0.2.2.9000

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error (on Mac) and solved it by updating pandoc to 2.11.3.1.